# SettingwithCopyWarning when passing Dataframe to function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a situation where this code is resulting in `SettingwithCopyWarning` warning...

```
def load(source):
   return pd.read_json(source)

def doStuff(df):
   ...

df = load('file.json')
doStuff(df) # -> SettingwithCopyWarning
```

But this is ok...

```
def doStuff(df):
   pd.read_json(source)
   ...

doStuff('file.json') # ok!
```

Why would loading the df in a separate function and passing it to another function result in this warning? I expect it to pass the same df by reference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)